# I want to install an Agent and a USM component in a empty computer whithout installing an application, how can i do this?

Tags: cloudify

I have a scenario that I want to use the Agent and USM component to implement the customer command to control a computer, but I donot want to install an application or a service,
how can i reach this goal?

thank you very much! 
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can install an empty service, one that does not actually run anything. This is often called a 'recipe about nothing'. It should look something like this:

```
service {
    name "empty"
    type "WEB_SERVER"

    lifecycle {

        locator {
            NO_PROCESS_LOCATORS
        }
    }

}
```

Add your custom commands here and you can run them from the Cloudify CLI/REST API as usual.
Note the use of the NO_PROCESS_LOCATORS directive - this tells the USM not to perform any process liveness scans.